# Why is a file still in repository, even though I've deleted it?

Tags: git

Is there a way to tell why is Git holding onto a file, even though I believe it has to let it go? I'm trying to rewrite the commits history by removing large files. Here's what I did:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter "rm -rf *.mp4" 573edba..HEAD
```

I've also tried:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.mp4' 573edba..HEAD
```

I saw them being reported as removed. I also ran `git gc`.

I have two branches in the repository, so I ran this on both the master and the development branches.

Now, if I do this:

```
git ls-files | grep '.mp4'
```

or

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only 573edba..HEAD | grep '.mp4'
```

I'm getting no results.

But then, when I examine the index file like so:

```
git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | grep -v chain | sort -k3nr
```

And then I take the first SHA1, and look at what it is:

```
git rev-list --all --objects | grep $SHA1
```

I get `/path/to/file.mp4`

---

The question: How do I get rid of that file once and forever? How do I know why is that file is still in the repository? What makes Git believe it has to be there?

Comment: Did you follow the "rest of the procedure" - i.e. removing your original branch/tag pointers from `refs/original/...`, clean out all your reflogs, and then do the `git repack`, `git prune`, etc. steps? If not, then either `refs/original/something` or one or more of your reflogs are still pointing at old commits where that file exists, and thus `git` won't discard those objects yet...

Comment: what if you try to clone into a completely new repository? Do you see the file you want to remove? Your sentence `rewrite the commits history` makes me think something (read like another client repository) is re-committing your changes. It may happen if someone else pulled the repository before you rewrote the history

Comment: @twalberg nope, I didn't, is there a way to find more info on how to do that?

Comment: @mardavi yes, tried that already, I'm getting an identical copy of what I have in the original one where I tried to delete files.

Comment: @twalberg omglol... after I did `git reflog exprire --expire=1.minute --all` the index file grew by 4 Mb :D I am / Git is so SAP...

Comment: @wvxvw One of the easiest ways would be to `git clone` the repository into another local copy, then copy the `.git/config` file from the old one into the new one to preserve your remote repository links. The `git help filter-branch` man page documents how to fully clean up at the end under the "CHECKLIST FOR SHRINKING A REPOSITORY" heading if you don't want to do it the `git clone` way...

Comment: @twalberg That will lose all the history / I do work on a copy of the repository anyway. I followed that man page to the letter, but no cigar.

Comment: Well, I guess you either want to get rid of the file, or you don't... You can either make your repository look like the file never existed (`git filter-branch` and full cleanup to remove its entire history) or just make sure the file is gone from the current commit and thus won't show up in future commits either (unless it's re-added; but it will still be in your repository in historic commits).

Answer (score 2):

Because `git filter-branch` is such a dangerous operation, a backup of your old branch heads is kept in `.git/refs/original`. That prevents `git gc` from deleting any objects referenced by those heads.

You just need to delete `.git/refs/original` and run `git gc` again or simply clone your local repo in order to actually remove all those big blobs from your repo.

Comment: did you run `git gc prune=now` again?

Comment: Yup, also `git gc --prune=now` and some other variations of the above.

Answer (score 1):

you have to update the git repository, use the following command:

```
git add -u .
git commit -m "some commit"
```

And then enjoy your life :D

Comment: Done, it says "nothing to commit, (working directory clean)". Though I think it tries to give me a hint: when I checkout another branch it says something like: Your branch and 'origin/development' have diverged, and have 120 and 120 different commit(s) each, respectively.

Comment: Oops, sorry for double post. I think what it is trying to say is that somehow I have now two distinct versions of the same branch, but it still keeps the old one for some reason.

Comment: mm ok, but now you are trying to delete the "old" branch?

Comment: Well, that's just a guess, I don't really know what that message is trying to say. I had two branches in origin: master and development, I've created local branches with the same name to track the remote branches. All changes I made so far I made to local branches. I pushed nothing at all yet.

Comment: The message is only information, it is told you how different are the branch you are checkout, in this case both have 120 commits. Maybe you need a merge is you like that the file disappear in the new branch

Comment: @rderoldan It's saying that the remote branch hasn't been updated yet. `git filter-branch` rewrites history, so the 120 commits in your local branch are now different from the 120 in your remote. Run `git push origin development -f` and that message will go away.

Comment: @Ajedi32 well, I didn't want to push before I make sure that what I push is what I intend to, especially not with `-f`, and this whole story being a complicated matter. But you were the closest to the culprit. I had to remove the origin from the repository I worked on to convince Git to remove the references to the remote branches - this gave me the accurate picture of what I really did on the local branches. If you want, you can make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question despite some good advices have been given before. This is because there were few things not mentioned otherwise.

Important things I needed to do in order to get it working:

- After `git filter-branch` I needed to delete file `.git/refs/original`.
- After that I had to call `git gc --prune=now`.
- After that `git repack -a -d`.
- Important notice: You have to delete remotes! `git remote rm origin`.
- Perhaps the sequence is incorrect, but repeating some of these steps should eventually get you to your goal.
- Push. Make sure that the server setting

---

```
[receive]
    denyNonFastforwards = false
```

- `git push -f`
- Hopefully, you can SSH to your server, because you aren't done yet!
- In your server repository, you again need to call `git gc` and `git repack` to finally shrink the repository removing the deleted files.